# {% url ... %} templatetag in Django included template not seeing variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm experiencing strange behaviour in an included template which I can't figure out.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = (
    path(
        "items/",
        views.list_view,
        name="list-view",
    ),
    path(
        "item/<int:pk>/",
        views.detail_view,
        name="detail-view",
    ),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def list_view(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, "parent_template.html", context={"items": items})

def detail_view(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "detail_template.html", context={"item": item}
```

**parent_template.html**

```
{% for item in items %}
  Parent: {{ item.pk }}
  {% include 'child_template.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

**child_template.html**

```
Child: {{ item.pk }}
URL: {% url 'detail-view' item.pk %}
```

I get a reverse error:

```
Reverse for '/test/url/<int:pk>/' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['test/url/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

If however I remove the `{% url ... %}` template tag, it renders correctly and shows:

Parent: 1
Child: 1

So it's clear that item is in the context, but for some reason it isn't being passed to the templatetag.

I have also tried variations like:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% with new_item=item %}
        {% include 'child_template.html' %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas?

I am using Django 3.2.12

Comment: Add your views and urls.py please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the error - I was looking in the wrong place. My complete code looked like this:

**parent.html**

```
<!-- {% include 'child_template.html' %} -->

{% for item in items %}
    {% with new_item=item %}
        {% include 'child_template.html' %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

I didn't pay attention to the HTML comment at the top of the template. Obviously Django is still rendering the code on the server side and at that point does not have item in its context.